# Compare value with array and get closest value to it

Tags: c#, arrays, compare

I'm a rookie in C# and I'm trying to learn that language.

Can you guys give me a tip how I can compare an array with a value picking the lowest from it?

like:

```
Double[] w = { 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000 };

double min = double.MaxValue;
double max = double.MinValue;

foreach (double value in w)
{
    if (value < min)
        min = value;
    if (value > max)
        max = value;
}

Console.WriteLine(" min:", min);
```

gives me the lowest value of `w`, how can I compare now?

If I have:

```
int p = 1001 + 2000;  // 3001
```

how can I compare now with the list of the array and find out that the (3000) value is the nearest value to my "Searchvalue"?

Comment: picking the lowest -> picking the value which gives the smallest difference?

Comment: Just to clarify, your Searchvalue is `p, which is 3001 in this case, and you want to compare it against your array `w and you want the result to be 3000, which is the value in the array that is nearest to 3001. Is this correct?

Comment: @user982998 Added one more solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with some simple mathematics and there are different approaches.

#### LINQ

```
Double searchValue = ...;

Double nearest = w.Select(p => new { Value = p, Difference = Math.Abs(p - searchValue) })
                  .OrderBy(p => p.Difference)
                  .First().Value;
```

#### Manually

```
Double[] w = { 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000 };

Double searchValue = 3001;
Double currentNearest = w[0];
Double currentDifference = Math.Abs(currentNearest - searchValue);

for (int i = 1; i < w.Length; i++)
{
    Double diff = Math.Abs(w[i] - searchValue);
    if (diff < currentDifference)
    {
        currentDifference = diff;
        currentNearest = w[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: after testing with 100.000 elements i can tell you your LinQ is **much** slow than your "Manually" solution but that's nothing new i guess but i was surprised that my solution is 2 as fast as your Manually solution i thought it would nearly the same but maybe the `Math.Abs()` is in your solution the part where the slowness comes from

Comment: @WiiMaxx Could be, but actually your solution is not working if the numbers are not sorted. So this is a more generally solution. But if you add another if ( for lower closest ) it still might be faster.

Comment: you are right it is still a little bit faster than your solution

Answer (score 1):

```
Double[] w = { 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000 };
var minimumValueFromArray = w.Min();
```

produces

`1000`, as expected, cause we execute [Enumerable.Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359972.aspx).

The same is for [Enumerable.Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358977.aspx), to figure out the max value:

```
Double[] w = { 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000 };
var maximumValueFromArray = w.Max();
```

Considering that you're comparing with the `double.MinValue` and `double.MaxValue`, I would assume that you want just pick the smallest and biggest value from array.

If this is not what you're searching for, please clarify.

Comment: double.MinValue was just for debug/ looking if he is picking the lowest/ heighest correctly

Comment: `Dump` is not a framework method and OP is a _"rookie in C# "_. So i would have explained that it's a LinqPad method (or simply omitted it). A link to `Enumerable.Min` and a few words to LINQ would habe been helpful also.

Answer (score 0):

based on your code, you can achieve this in a very easy way

```
    Double[] w = { 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000 }; // it has to be sorted

    double search = 3001;
    double lowerClosest = 0;
    double upperClosest = 0;


        for (int i = 1; i < w.Length; i++)
        {
            if (w[i] > search)
            {
                upperClosest = w[i];
                break; // interrupts your foreach
            }

        }
        for (int i = w.Length-1; i >=0; i--)
        {
            if (w[i] <= search)
            {
                lowerClosest = w[i];
                break; // interrupts your foreach
            }

        }

    Console.WriteLine(" lowerClosest:{0}", lowerClosest);
    Console.WriteLine(" upperClosest:{0}", upperClosest);
    if (upperClosest - search > search - lowerClosest)
        Console.WriteLine(" Closest:{0}", lowerClosest);
    else
        Console.WriteLine(" Closest:{0}", upperClosest);

    Console.ReadLine();
```

depending on the position of your search value this will be **less than O(n)**

Answer (score -2):

```
                Performance wise custom code will be more use full. 

                List<int> results;
                int targetNumber = 0;
                int nearestValue=0;
                if (results.Any(ab => ab == targetNumber ))
                {
                    nearestValue= results.FirstOrDefault<int>(i => i == targetNumber );
                }
                else
                {
                    int greaterThanTarget = 0;
                    int lessThanTarget = 0;
                    if (results.Any(ab => ab > targetNumber ))
                    {
                        greaterThanTarget = results.Where<int>(i => i > targetNumber ).Min();
                    }
                    if (results.Any(ab => ab < targetNumber ))
                    {
                        lessThanTarget = results.Where<int>(i => i < targetNumber ).Max();
                    }

                    if (lessThanTarget == 0 )
                    {
                        nearestValue= greaterThanTarget;
                    }
                    else if (greaterThanTarget == 0)
                    {
                        nearestValue= lessThanTarget;
                    }
                    else if (targetNumber - lessThanTarget < greaterThanTarget - targetNumber )
                    {
                        nearestValue= lessThanTarget;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            nearestValue= greaterThanTarget;
                    }
                }
```