# Finding the closest figure based on input in 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm fairly new to c# and am having a bit of an issue with 2D arrays (please excuse my lack of terminology). Say I have a 2D array, hypothetically looking like something as below:

1.2    1.32     1.37     1.9    1.91    1.95     1.97

2.5    2.55     2.71     2.85    2.87    2.9    2.98

3.9    ...      ...      ...    ...    ...    ...

...

User input is random, for the purpose of my understanding, say the input is 2.54. How would I return the closest figure?

Thanks.

Comment: Does each row correspond to numbers between x and x+1 (x starting from 1)? Is the array sorted?

Comment: Have you tried anything? For example, how would you solve the same problem with a one-dimensional array?

Comment: Or even on the paper?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894550/compare-value-with-array-and-get-closest-value-to-it

Comment: @gargankit Yes, the numbers are restrained to x and x+1 and the array is sorted.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That's the issue, I'm really not getting how to access a specific figure within an array; and after having failed to come up with anything I came here.

Comment: Did you check the link provided by @GeraldGrimaldoAbellon ??

Comment: @JamesAnderson: Ok, so your question is not specific to two-dimensional arrays? I think you should start with the simpler case of one-dimensional arrays then. For a start, how would you solve the same problem with a fixed number of figures?

Answer (score 0):

Confirm if this works though; I'm not sure.

```
    public static double SearchArray(double inValToSearch_, double[,] inArr_)
    {
        if (inArr_ == null || inArr_.Length == 0)
            return 0;

        double closestVal = inArr_[0, 0];
        for (int i = 0; i < inArr_.GetLength(0); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < inArr_.GetLength(1); j++)
                if (inValToSearch_ - inArr_[i, j] > inValToSearch_ - closestVal)
                    closestVal = inArr_[i, j];

        return closestVal;
    }
```